# The tag suggester shouldn't suggest synonyms of tags that you've already used

Tags: bug, suggested-tags

I was composing a question about Postgres on Stack Overflow, and had tagged the question with "postgres". The tag suggester, seeing that my question was about PostgreSQL, dutifully informed me that I ought to add "postgresql" as a tag as well.

[image: tags and suggestions]

But Postgres and PostgreSQL are the same thing! And the tag suggestion engine should know that, because "postgres" and "postgresql" are synonyms.

This seems like a (very minor) bug, or at least undesirable behavior - the tag suggester shouldn't suggest synonyms of tags you've already used.

Comment: It probably shouldn't suggest synonyms at all. Not sure off-hand if that's feasible performance-wise, though.

Comment: @Anna did you have chance to look into it?